# What are the option types for creating options in the bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

The create an option for the Bigcommerce API says that "name" and "type" are required for creating an option. developer.bigcommerce.com shows a sample request like this.

{
"name": "Color",
"type": "CS",
"display_name": "Color"
}

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation of what the type codes are.

Comment: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CS = Color Swatch
RB = Radio Button
S = Select
RT = Rectangle
C = Checkbox
PI = Product list with photos
P = Product list without photos

You can see more indepth information [here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Importing-Product-Options/)